# searching examples of functions that can be written as recursion with base cases

Tags: c, recursion, iteration

I want to use recursion on some iterative example in c. I wounder how I see when there will be a meaningful base case(a base case that returns something).

My problem is that I can't see in which other cases that will bee really use of base cases other then writing a recursive function to calculate the Fibonacci series.

Can you give me examples of problems where I either can write a function as a iterative function or a function with recursion that uses base cases.

Comment: factorial is a classic one

Comment: Can you write a recursive function that *doesn't* have a base case? Seems like infinite descent to me (or, more practically, stack overflow [rather apropos, if I may say so]).

Comment: There's Ackermann's function.  You might consider Tower of Hanoi. You could consider converting an integer to a string (there are recursive versions of that).  There's quick sort and related algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Expression evaluation is one classic case of recursion.

If your expression has sub-expressions, you evaluate each recursively.  If your expression is a constant or an identifier, then you have reached the base case.  In contrast, the iterative approach requires that you you push partial results on a stack.